# Example for Office Add-Ins for Mac?

Tags: ms-office, office-addins, office-js

I would like to develop Add-in for office Word for Mac (2011 and later). But I cannot find any manuals about Add-Ins development.

Can anybody know how to develop Add-Ins for Office for Mac?

It will be good if anybody suggest me link of Example.  I have tried but didn't get any sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news is that you can use almost all the APIs documented [here](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/body?product=word) for MAC as well!

You also want to read [this article](http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/sideload-an-office-add-in-on-ipad-and-mac) about how to try your add-ins in MAC or iOS.

Finally make sure you are on the latest possible build! (15,22 as of right now).

Happy coding!!!

Answer (score 1):

The process for building JavaScript add-ins for Mac is pretty much the same as building them for other platforms. There are some specific instructions for [debugging on Mac](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/debug-office-add-ins-on-ipad-and-mac).

However, Office Add-Ins for Mac are only supported starting with [Office for Mac 2016](http://dev.office.com/add-in-availability) (and even then I believe it needs to be a recent update).